# How to open folder which I have created in my app in Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making one app to add watermark to video using FFMPEG library.and I have create one directory `/sdcard/Pictures/Video Stamper/` to store output video with watermark.

now in mp app I have made one button called `Output Folder` when user click that button then it will automatically browse user to my output video directory which I have created previously(`/sdcard/Pictures/Video Stamper/`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code for that

```
public void openFolder(){
     Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFolder/");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "*/*");

    if (intent.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null)
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        // if you reach this place, it means there is no any file 
       } 
}
```

Comment: @MilanTejani I have changed my code please check now

Comment: this code is working third party file manager but it not working on default file manager of smartphone